# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from test prog on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

while test in simulator it work very well , while in device it raise the following error and warning

```
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c++
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

how to override that please

Comment: Ultimate solution: clean all, delete from device, rebuild. sometimes it helps.

Comment: I did but the same error

Comment: Post your code -- the debugger should give you the line where the error is occurring, as well as the stack trace.  We're not psychic.

Comment: Adam, the debugger won't give you a line number if it's this kind of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say why you are getting the error on the device but not the simulator.  As far as your warning about not finding the symbol, you can resolve that if you follow the instructions here:

[libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib is missing in iOS 4.2.1 development SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284277/libxcodedebuggersupport-dylib-is-missing-in-ios-4-2-1-development-sdk)

Specifically

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols
```

and

```
ln -s ../../4.2\ \(8C134\)/Symbols/Developer/ Developer
```

Trinca (https://stackoverflow.com/users/529803/trinca) deserves credit for this.

Back to your problem, you can read about how to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS at
http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

You should also enable Guard Malloc
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html
(found this at [EXC_BAD_ACCESS on device, but fine on Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583728/exc-bad-access-on-device-but-fine-on-simulator))

Thanks Lou Franco - I voted you up man :)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3937/lou-franco

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to a released object or something with memory.
Check your program iVars, one of them is either not retained or released before you finished using it.

Comment: You could retain the object your having a exec_bad_access with OR you can make a @property (retain) NSString *myString; and then when you populate that iVar you can do something like [self setMyString:newValue] and it will retain it for you. (dont forget to release at the dealloc later)