# iOS app crashes on first load on device

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, launch

XCode 4.2 with iOS 5

My app will only crash on the first load on a real device while debugging.  If I run it in the simulator, it always works.  And every time after the first time on the device itself, it always works fine.

Once I delete the app from the phone, the next launch of the app will crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS but I cannot tell where this is happening even while debugging.

The app failed submission to the app store for this reason.   All I can say is that it happens RIGHT before the dialog:  "MyApp" Would like to Use Your Current Location

Then when I re-launch it, it works fine.

Here is the crash log, but it doesnt seem to tell us much:

```
Incident Identifier: 2E1B994F-6783-4C3E-8463-F21B4AD0BE9D
CrashReporter Key:   d4365cbed4fa63fb6536c6c6925416357a62e6e7
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         MyApp [4205]
Path:            MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-12 11:09:17.223 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x35e85f30
Highlighted Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x007f3000      r2: 0x60000000      r3: 0xfffff000
    r4: 0x60000000    r5: 0x007f3000      r6: 0x00000907      r7: 0x2fdfe780
    r8: 0x3eac9690    r9: 0x31bcc104     r10: 0x00000106     r11: 0x00000080
    ip: 0xfffffff3    sp: 0x2fdfe774      lr: 0x35e864d9      pc: 0x35e85f30
  cpsr: 0x200f0010
```

Binary images description not available

Comment: lookup zombies re:iPhone dev and turn them on in your debugger (and maybe accept some answers)

Comment: I do use Zombies but from what I see and what I've read, you cant use it while connected to the phone, only the Simulator.

Comment: then it's probably time to insert a whole bunch of NSLog statements - or go through your code line by line verifying EVERY data item prior to that dialog popping up.

Comment: I know where it ends...but once it hands off control to CLLocationController, it crashes.  Right after this line:  [CLController.locMgr startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

Comment: And you have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583728/exc-bad-access-on-device-but-fine-on-simulator

Comment: I was able to enable zombies Product -> Edit Scheme... -> Diagnostics and when it crashes it says:  [UIImage release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x216230  But I am not releasing any images anywhere in the app.